# Error 400 Bad Request, Discord Add Guild Member guild.join

Tags: php, discord

I'm trying from several hours to understand why the request is not good.

This is how I do the request:

`$url = 'https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/610214145396047904/members/277459004282634242';`

```php
function PutRequest($url, $Token) {
  //Initiate cURL
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  //header
  $headers = array(
    "Authorization" => 'Bot MyBotToken',
    "Content-Type" => 'application/json'
  );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

  //Our JSON with access token.
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
  '{"access_token" : "'. $Token .'"}');

  //Execute the request.
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  return $response;
}
```

[print_r of the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJlYL.png)

Comment: response looks like you are getting an error message from cloudflare which is a proxy between the target service. If cloudflare needs to block a request, your payload might be suspicious to them, like headers